# failing to install RVM while trying to install RoR

Tags: command-line, rvm, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to install RoR on my system. I am following [digital ocean's](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin-with-rvm) tutorial. While I try to install RVM `\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable` with this command I am getting the below error:

```
gpg: Signature made Tuesday 31 March 2015 03:22:13 AM IST using RSA key ID BF04FF17
gpg: Can't check signature: public key not found
Warning, RVM 1.26.0 introduces signed releases and automated check of signatures when GPG software found.
Assuming you trust Michal Papis import the mpapis public key (downloading the signatures).

GPG signature verification failed for '/home/suraj/.rvm/archives/rvm-1.26.11.tgz' - 'https://github.com/rvm/rvm/releases/download/1.26.11/1.26.11.tar.gz.asc'!
try downloading the signatures:

    gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3

or if it fails:

    command curl -sSL https://rvm.io/mpapis.asc | gpg --import -

the key can be compared with:

    https://rvm.io/mpapis.asc
    https://keybase.io/mpapis
```

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5413775/1596460

Comment: It may also help to `rm -rf` (delete) your .gpg/ directory.  (ONLY assuming you don't need anything that's in there)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a security feature introduced in the latest version of RVM, so you have to import the keys manually. Do what the error suggests:

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3
```

The `gpg` command contacts a public key server and requests a key associated with the given ID. In this case we are requesting the RVM project's key which is used to sign each RVM release. Having the RVM project's public key allows us to verify the legitimacy of the RVM release we will be downloading, which is signed with the matching private key.

Comment: try Ron solution as first thing..if that didn't work for you try `curl -sSL https://rvm.io/mpapis.asc | sudo gpg --import -`

Comment: `gpg: requesting key D39DC0E3 from hkp server keys.gnupg.net
?: keys.gnupg.net: Host not found
gpgkeys: HTTP fetch error 7: couldn't connect: Success
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0`

This is what I get with Ron's solution

Comment: I still get the same error after trying these solutions@Ron and @Pradeep

Comment: Are you behind a firewall? Try [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1492290)

Comment: not sure how to solve this

Comment: I couldn't connect to this while I was using a VPN. Once I turned it off, I was able to get the key.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem occurred because .gnupg directory was the root owner. The solution Is set the correct user and group with **chown** command.

Answer (score 0):

Lafitte pointed me in the right direction. I would like to elaborate on his answer, but don't have points to comment. So here's my contribution:

```
sudo chown -R `whoami`:somegroup ~/.gnupg
```

Obviously replace 'somegroup' with which ever group your user belongs to.